# HQL update query with complex inner queries

Tags: c#, hibernate, postgresql, nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to update `Guild.League` when its members total `TournamentXP` = 0:

```
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        const int maxLeagues = 6;
        session.CreateQuery(
            @"update Guild g set g.League = g.League + 1 where g.League < " + maxLeagues + @" 
                AND g.Id in (
                    select GuildId from (
                       select GuildId, SUM(u.TournamentXP) AS s from User u where GuildId != 0 group by u.GuildId) r
                    where r.s = 0)
        ").ExecuteUpdate();

        tx.Commit();
    }
```

The query throws "Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException" near line 3, column 48 of the query.

The original postgresql query (which runs fine) looks like:

```
update guilds set league = league + 1 where league <= 5 
                AND id in (
                    select guild_id from (
                       select guild_id, SUM(u.tournament_xp) AS s from users u where guild_id != 0 group by u.guild_id) r
                    where r.s = 0)
```

How to make it work in HQL?

Also if you can propose any optimization for the query I will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because HQL doesn't support subqueries on FROM clause.
It supports only on select/where clauses.

So either use native SQL (or) convert your inner subquery from clause into where clause.

BTW you can directly use HAVING clause and avoid inner subquery in from clause as below:

```
AND g.Id in (
 select u.GuildId from User u where u.GuildId != 0
 group by u.GuildId
 having SUM(u.TournamentXP) = 0
)
```

Comment: Yeah, that works! Can you give any advice on how to transform queries with FROM subqueries to join or something supported by HQL in case having does not suit?